# Customising Horizontal scroll bar using MFC

Tags: mfc, cedit

I m trying to customise the Horizontal scrollbar for a view in MFC edit control.
and trying to set ScrollInfo to the same.

```
SCROLLINFO ScrollInfo;
   ScrollInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
   ScrollInfo.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE;
   ScrollInfo.nMin = 1;
   ScrollInfo.nMax = INT_MAX;
SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ, &ScrollInfo, TRUE);
```

But the scrollbar is not setting up to the actual width of page.

Am I missing something.?
I have attached the image also that shows the difference between the standard horizontal scrollbar and the customised horizontal scrollbar.

[image: Example]

Comment: Overriding `CEdit`'s scrollbar is not trivial, I don't think. Showing the declaration for `SCROLLINFO` does not explain anything.

Comment: You set the `SIF_PAGE` flag but you forgot to initialize `ScrollInfo.nPage`.

Comment: Thank you.. for a vertical scroll bar i have set the ScrollInfo.nPage to the number of lines in the page. But i m confused for horizontal scroll bar as the width keeps varying.